# Private/Public Variables in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I come from Java and i have learned to never set a Variable public. Always make a variable private and make her accessable over setter and getter methods.

I started with C# the last days and im actually getting problems with this:

```
String Name { get; set; }
```

From other classes i can not access to the variable "Name"

so i thought this might be a good solution:

```
 String Name { public get; public set; }
```

but yes ... does not work.

Do i have to make every variable public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining a property, not a field.  This is equivalent to creating a `getName` and `setName` in Java and an associated private field.

The syntax you are using is shorthand for doing this.

To make it accessible set the property to public.

```
public String Name { get; set; }
```

If you don't want the set method to be accesible you can mark it private:

```
public String Name { get; private set; }
```

This will cause the compiler to create code equivalent to the following:

```
private String _name;

public String GetName()
{
    return _name;
}

private void SetName(String name)
{
    _name = name;
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you! Now i understood the difference between a field and a  property.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make property `public`

```
public String Name { get; set; }
```

Class members are `private` by default.

Comment: Note, you can also make a public getter, and private (or protected) setter: `public String Name { get; private set; }`

Comment: I know this way to access the variable, but is it best practise? I hope this question is not too stupid ... like i said, i learned to make every variable private

Comment: Visual Studio created private member automatically `_Name`

Comment: @jens12345675432 what do you mean by best practice ? if you wanna access the property from other classes, and if those classes don't inherit from your class then making it `public` is the only way to do this.if don't want it to be changed from outside then you can make the setter private as suggested in the first comment

Answer (score 1):

These are properties, not fields. Properties in C# are the same as getter and setter methods in Java. To make them public you should have `public string Name { get; set;}`.

Generally you shouldn't have too many of these on your classes as it breaks encapsulation and is symptomatic of a bad design.

Comment: Saying "Generally you shouldn't have too many of these...it breaks encapsulation and is symptomatic of a bad design" is a pretty broad statement. Can you elaborate on what you mean? This automatic property syntax is just shorthand for the extended property get/set methods (one of the things I'm glad the C# team sort of adopted from Objective-C recently). Surely an object needs to expose properties. Are you saying that too many properties is bad because it's symptomatic of a class that doesn't serve one and only one purpose?

Comment: I personally believe a lot of OO developers tend towards what Martin Fowler calls an anemic domain model (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) where most objects in the model expose fields via properties and all the behaviour is contained in other "service" classes. Of course I use properties but it can be easy to go over the top and end up with code that is not really object oriented. I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the viewpoint and have enjoyed what I've read so far of the article you referenced. So, my only observation would be that one reason the property-bag model "seems to be having a particular spurt at the moment" is because there are so many architectures making use of DTO's (data transfer objects) to marshal data back and forth across various types of boundaries. This is sort of at the heart of AJAX and many ORM's, for instance.

Comment: Okay, so now I've read past the first paragraph. :-)  The author is obviously referring to service architectures, which is what I'm referring to, as well. The thing about those is that they're often distributed, and the services that use the data often aren't made out of the same parts. So putting all the behavior into the objects if your objects are, say, Java, doesn't do you any good when you marshal those objects to another platform (JavaScript), because the *behavior* cannot be marshaled.

Comment: I actually **like** the OO concept of encapsulation (data and behavior) a lot. I just think practicality sort of forces our hand sometimes. But I'm eager to discover and learn about cleaner solutions. I do dislike most ORM's, though, just because the abstraction usually comes at such a high performance cost.

Comment: You would marshal the data as a DTO (POCO) and then have a translation layer which would move the data into your domain objects to do all the complex business logic. That said, I understand for simple apps that this may be overkill and everything I am saying is very "pure" OO - all projects are a mixture of different styles of programming. If you search a little, Greg Young has some videos on YouTube about CQRS & DDD which introduces some interesting concepts for modelling complex domains and I find his advice quite pragmatic. Hope I didn't digress too far!

Comment: Not as far as I'm concerned. I figured you acquitted the initial brevity of your answer well enough to get an upvote (click). I'll check out those references when I get a minute. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Selman22 already gave you a concise and accurate answer, extended with comments by @Mike Christensen. (essentially, you are talking about `Properties`). You may also consider an option available in C# to use `Internal` access modifier, applied to types or members that are accessible only within files in the same assembly, so less visible from the outside world.
Best regards,